# Is it possible to prove that for $x,y,z \in \Bbb{R}$; if $x,y,z >0$ and $xyz=1$, then $(x+y+z)\ge 3$ without using the AM-GM inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, sum-of-squares-method, uvw

I'm asked in an exercise from an algebra textbook to prove that for$\{ x,y,z\} \subset \Bbb{R}$; if  $x,y,z >0$ and $xyz=1$, then $x+y+z\ge 3$.

Using the arithmetic and geometric mean inequality the proof is easy. But in this book the definitions of roots, logarithms and inductive sets are introduced in later chapters. So I guess there is a  way to prove it without AM-GM because most proofs of the AM-GM inequality that I'm aware of requiere either induction or logarithms and the inequality itself involves a root.

Can anyone please help me? Is there a proof without using AM-GM?

Comment: That **is** the AM/GM inequality for three variables;  the general case follows easily from that particular case.

Comment: There are relatively painless proofs of AM-GM, for example [this one, by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proof_by_induction_.231) to prove the general case (even though you only need $n=3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof without AM-GM.

Let $x=a^3$, $y=b^3$ and $z=c^3$.

Hence, $abc=1$ and
$$x+y+z-3=a^3+b^3+c^3-3=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=$$
$$=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)((a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2)\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: That **is** a proof of AM/GM for three variables.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown There are other ways without using AM-GM.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

We need to prove that 
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc\geq0.$$
Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, our inequality is a linear inequality of $v^2$ because it's third degree.

Thus, it remains to prove our inequality for an extremal value of $v^2$,

which happens for equality case of two variables.

Since the last inequality is homogeneous and symmetric, we can assume $v=c=1$,

which gives $$a^3+2-3a\geq0$$ or
$$(a+2)(a-1)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: And another${}$!

Answer (score 0):

Also, we can use SOS here:
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=\sum_{cyc}(a^3-abc)=\sum_{cyc}a(a^2-bc)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}a((a-b)(a+c)-(c-a)(a+b))=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)(a(a+c)-b(b+c))=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)(a^2-b^2+ac-bc)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b+c)\geq0.$$

Comment: Another proof of AM/GM for three variables.